# Count the number of triplets a*b=c

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The problem is to count the number of triplets such that

```
a * b = c
where a1 <= a <= a2 and b1 <= b <= b2 and c1 <= c <= c2
```

Input will be a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2

The solution that I can think is to use two nested loop that iterates from a1 to a2 and second one from b1 to b2 and multiply each of them and see if the multiplied value lies in the range c1 to c2 then increment the count.

How to efficiently solve the problem when constraints are very high i.e all a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 can have value between 0 to 1000000000.

Comment: What is the type of `a,b,c`?

Comment: the type of a b c is integer

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I would update the ranges of either a1,a2 or b1,b2 by `b1'=c1/a1` and `b2'=c2/a2`. Thus the number of tripples should be `(b2'-b1'+1)*(a2-a1+1)`. Of course the corner cases should be taken into consideration. I am short on time right now. I will try to create a fuul answer later...

Comment: @AlexLop: Your idea is good, but you can't have a closed formula for all numbers; you must do your adjustment for each individual `a`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part 1: Solution with O(a2 - a1) complexity.

First, notice that given a certain `a`, we can easily count the number of `b` values with `b1 <= b <= b2`, which also satisfy `c1 <= a * b <= c2`. The latter condition is equivalent to `c1 / a <= b <= c2 / a`, thus we need to count the number of integers b which satisfy `max(b1, c1/a) <= b <= min(b2, c2/a)`.

This number is `N(a) = floor(min(b2, c2/a)) - ceil(max(b1, c1/a)) + 1` -- relation `(1)`.

The solution to the problem is `N(a1) + N(a1 + 1) + ... + N(a2)`.

This is more efficient than looping over all `(a, b)` pairs and checking their product, however, it may still not be fast enough for the given magnitude of the inputs -- the complexity is `O(a2 - a1)`. Since the problem is symmetrical in `a` and `b`, it might be more advantageous to use the `O(b2 - b1)` complexity.

In the following two parts I will describe a more efficient solution.

---

### Part 2: Reducing the problem to simpler ones.

Let us denote as `N(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2)` the value that we need to calculate.

Notice that we can reduce the problem into two problems with c1 = 0, using:

`N(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2) = N(a1, a2, b1, b2, 0, c2) - N(a1, a2, b1, b2, 0, c1 - 1)`.

We can take this further and reduce a problem where c1 = 0 into two problems where b1 = 0 and c1 = 0. This can be done using:

`N(a1, a2, b1, b2, 0, C) = N(a1, a2, 0, b2, 0, C) - N(a1, a2, 0, b1 - 1, 0, C)`.

Similarly, we can reduce a problem where b1 = 0 and c1 = 0 into two problems with a1 = 0, b1 = 0, c1 = 0.

Therefore, it is enough to solve simpler problems which require to compute values of the following form: `N(0, A, 0, B, 0, C)`, *i.e.* we need to count the number of triplets of natural numbers `(a, b, c)`, with `c = a * b`, `a <= A`, `b <= B`, `c <= C`.

---

### Part 3: Solution with O(sqrt(c2)) complexity.

One next useful observation is that since `a * b = c <= C`, at least one of the following relations is true: `a <= sqrt(C)`, or `b <= sqrt(C)` -- observation `(2)`.

In the first part of the proof (relation `1`) it was shown that we can efficiently calculate (in `O(1)`) the number of good `b` values if `a` is fixed. Using that relation, we can efficiently count the number of triples with `a <= sqrt(C)` -- in `O(sqrt(C))`.

What remains to do is to calculate the number of triplets with `a > sqrt(C)`. According to observation `(2)`, we know that in this case it is required to have `b <= sqrt(C)`.

Thus, for any `b` in `{0, 1, 2, ..., sqrt(C)}` we have to count the number of good `a` values such that `sqrt(C) < a < A`. We can once again apply relation `(1)` (with reversed roles for `a` and `b` this time -- we are now given `b` and calculate the number of good `a` values, which is subject to the constraint of belonging to a certain interval). For each `b` in `{0, 1, 2, ..., sqrt(C)}`, we can count the number of good `a` in `O(1)` -- therefore the complexity for this case is again `O(sqrt(C))`.

Using the above results, we get an overall complexity of `O(sqrt(C))`. Returning to the initial problem, this involves an `O(sqrt(c2))` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fac that a*b = b*a. I.e. if you have tried a=2, b=3, there is no sense in also trying a=3, b=2.

Also, once a*b > c2, there is no sense in increasing a or b.